# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt'

Tags: python, tensorflow

My code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
# import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
```

When I run it, get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt'
```

Also, instead of `from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt` I used `from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt` but it did not change anything.

I use TensorFlow version 1.14.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth mentioning https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/error-converting-tensorflow-model-to-tensorrt-on-windows-10/83892 its not supported on windows 10

Comment: Please be careful with posting very similar answers to multiple questions.

Answer (score 0):

In version that lower then 1.14.1 the right import is:

```py
import tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt as trt
```

Comment: import tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt as trt doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

`from tensorflow.python.compiler.mlcompute import mlcompute`

for setting the GPU device in Metal plugin. We honor the Tensorflow's device placement logic. So depending on the supported operations in Metal plugin the layers will be mapped to GPU by TF's device placer. You can use `tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement`(
True) to dump out the layers mapped to GPU. I just removed the mlcompute import below and was able to train the network.